# How to run junit tests at build time in netbeans and jenkins?

Tags: netbeans, build, junit, jenkins

I'm trying to set up a project to run junit tests at build time, so that every member of the team and the Jenkins build server runs the tests when it builds.

I believe we have set up a fairly standard webproject in Netbeans, but I can't seem to find anyone solving this problem on stackoverflow or google.

How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to file: /nbproject/build-impl.xml and fidn the dist target. It should look like this:

`<target depends="init,compile,-pre-dist,do-dist,-post-dist" description="Build distribution (WAR)." name="dist"/>`

Copy paste it into /build.xml, and add the "test" target into it:

`<target depends="init,compile,test,-pre-dist,do-dist,-post-dist" description="Build distribution (WAR)." name="dist"/>`

This was in Netbeans 7.3. It now builds and runs the tests on every build, also on the Jenkins build server.

Comment: I would recommend that that you put the "test" target after compile and before "-pre-dist"  like this `depends="init,compile,test,-pre-dist,do-dist,-post-dist"`.  Ant executes dependencies in the order listed and you probably want to run your tests before creating your war file.

Comment: Ah yeah, that makes sense. Thanks :)
I just thought I would put it last as I thought that would disrupt everything else the least.

Comment: Ok I just wanted to come back to this, because I found out the idiomatic way of doing this. This manual edit in the build-impl.xml file kept getting reset by automatically generated changes, so I researched this again, and found that I just needed to write "test dist" without the quotes in the Build->Invoke Ant->Targets field in the Jenkins build configuration.

Voila.

Comment: It might not matter in your case, but invoking both "test" and "dist" targets will re-run "init", and "compile" for each target.  I think ant only runs each dependency once *per target*.  Check your jenkins console output to see how many times "init" is invoked.

Comment: Yeah there is a lot of duplication of init and compile targets now, and the compile takes almost twice as long. But I don't know how to solve this. Maybe there is some sub taget for dist, that skips the init and compile?

Comment: The easiest way is to probably create a new empty target called "jenkins" or "ci" that depends on "test" and "dist".  And then just run that new target from jenkins.  That way everything will only run once.

Comment: Ok. I tried doing that, and it worked fine on Jenkins, it got rid of all the duplicate build targets. But it I couldn't figure out how to change Netbeans default F11 build target - it always just runs clean and dist when you press F11.

So what i ended up doing was to override the dist target in build.xml, and just add test to the depends value. Voila, now it doesn't get overridden by new autogenerated build-impl.xml files, and it runs the tests in Netbeans and Jenkins at build time without doing it twice for several targets.

Answer (score 1):

Never modify your build-impl.xml! Netbeans regenerates this file when you perform any changes to your project.

The better approach would be to modify your build.xml and add a post-jar task:

```
<target name="-post-jar" depends="test"/>
```

Comment: Legend! Adding the depends attribute worked for me!